# Error "No module named PyQt5.QtCore" in QGIS standalone application

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt, standalone

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.6\apps\qgis\python')
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.6\apps\qgis\bin')
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.6\apps\Python37')
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.6\apps\Python37\Scripts')
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.6\apps\Qt5\bin')
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.6\apps\Python27\Scripts')
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.6\bin')
sys.path.append(r'C:\Windows\System32')
sys.path.append(r'C:\Windows')
sys.path.append(r'C:\Windows\System32\wbem')
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.6\apps\Python37\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32')
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.6\apps\Python37\Lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs')
import qgis
```

I would like to write a standalone QGIS application. My Python file is on the desktop and I would like to access the QGIS functions. At the beginning I had the error `import qgis module not found`, which could be solved by the first line of `sys.path.append`. Now I get the error:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtCore'
```

Although I have appended many different paths to the environment variables, I keep getting this error.

How do I solve this error and use the QGIS functions in a standalone application?

Error trying the anwser:
[image: Error]

Comment: do you have the line `from PyQt5.QtCore import *` in your script or does `import qgis` raise the error?

Comment: the `import qgis` raises the error

Comment: Have you read this already? https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#running-custom-applications

Comment: yes I did this already and I am still getting the error.

Answer (score 4):

You must be using different Python from the installed one by QGIS installation. When I try to run the script using a different Python interpreter (`C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe`) not installed by QGIS I get the same error.

To be sure this is the reason:

- Add `print("DONE!")` after the line `import qgis` in your script above.
- Save the script as a Python file. (for example, `test.py` in `C:\test` folder)
- Open OSGeo Shell.

  [image]
- Run `py3_env`.

  [image]
- Run `python c:\test\test.py`.

You probably won't get error and it will print `DONE!`. That means you didn't use the Python interpreter installed by QGIS.

To solve this, either run the `.py` file in "OSGeo Shell" as mentioned above or set Python environment for the editor you use. For example, you have an option to [select a Python interpreter in VSCode editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) before running the file.

Comment: Yeah I know I did this already ! But for me its necessary to get QGIS running in a not QGIS-python-environment, because I want to transfer the standalone application to another computer.

Comment: Or can you help me writing a batch-file maybe to automatically open the OSGeo4W Shell and run this needed commands ? I just tried doing that, but failed again.

Comment: and I also get an error, when I try to do it like that, I added the error in my original question !

Comment: I don't encounter that error. I have no solution. You can check [these search results](https://www.google.com/search?q="no+module+named+qgis"+site:gis.stackexchange.com&client=opera&hs=Ntv&sxsrf=ALeKk0124eF6xBsvI1XwOJXzN4N_TOxw-A:1619091228450&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwis8J7s4JHwAhU-gv0HHf_eAfAQrQIoBHoECAoQBQ&biw=2560&bih=1299). There are different solutions for that error in GIS.SE.

Comment: I already checked every page there :D I really dont know whats going wrong there